# JPA table capitalization inconsistent

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

We're using a very basic JPA implementation that should create tables consistently from our models.
I believe we're using EclipseLink or TopLink (whichever one is default with the latest Netbeans/Glassfish).  The problem is, the tables are created with inconsistent capitaliztion and with the columns out of order.  For me, It creates the `"User"` table as "user", and for other members of my team it creates `"USER"`.

I've tried using the `@Table annotation (@Table(name="USer"))`, but it doesn't work.

How do we get EclipseLink to generate consistent table names?  Frankly this seems like a rather amateurish mistake for a framework like this.

Sub-question : the reason this is a problem is because EclipseLink by default has no default way of managing schema/data migrations, as far as I know of.  The way we're handling it is by writing a bunch of `INSERT INTO's` to bootstrap the objects we need in our database, and drop-and-recreating the tables every time the schema changes.  I **know** this is not the best practice for propagating schema changes -- does anyone know how this is typically handled in a standard JPA implementation?

Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using? Are you and your team members working on different operating systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never found any good answer for this.  Luckily, we found a workaround for the ways we were using to update the table, which didn't care about capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

By default EclipseLink uses all upper case for the table name, the class User would be USER.

If you specify an @Table annotation with name="USer", then the table will be created as "USer".

Perhaps you are using your own scripts to create the tables, or you database is changing the case based on the OS or its own settings.  What database are you using?

If you enable logging in EclipseLink, it will show the exact DDL that it is executing (if it is executing DDL).

In EclipseLink 2.4 there is also a "create-or-extend-tables" DDL generation option to alter existing tables.